# "How to ask a smart question" overhaul

Tags: support, stack-overflow, homework, troubleshooting

I'm speaking strictly about Stack Overflow here, but shouldn't there be some kind of reference to the ability to troubleshooting?

It seems as if more and more SO users are seeking help with their 'homework' and are less and less developing. When it comes to the 'homework' questions, they're easy to spot because they show up multiple times in a week or even a night.

But the actual developers, the ones you'd like to take seriously and put some effort into assisting seem to lack any ability at all to troubleshoot their own code. Why must we constantly remind them to look at their debuggers, their console logs, report errors or generate jsFiddle pages? What can we, as caring, responsible and helpful coders do to ensure that SO users don't just slap a page of code up and ask what's wrong?

Can we develop a "how to troubleshoot" diagram? Can we ask more specific questions about what troubleshooting tools and methods the users have implemented? And most of all, how do we instil the fact that coding skills are worth ZIP-ZERO-NADA-ZILCH-SQUAT without the ability to troubleshoot and narrow down errors?

Comment: Could you add some paragraphs to that?

Comment: I'm sure I could, but my 9-5 takes precedence. Anyone is welcome to continue on with this though process and add whatever they see as relevant.

Comment: For someone focusing on the issue of good questions, that's a surprising attitude. But well, done ....

Comment: i dont get why this getting downvotes. it's quite well written and its has a point

Comment: Related: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/25936)

Comment: @mehow I'm guessing the downvotes where for the [first version](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/200227/1) of the question that was a bit hard to read.

Comment: Just one remark: the programmers that "just slap a page of code up and ask what's wrong" are the good ones! Heaps and heaps of users just post vague descriptions about how they get "an error" without even posting one letter of code! And don't get me started on the tags. They don't think, they just type in some tags that they think sound interesting, but that have nothing to do with the problem in any way whatsoever!

Comment: @MrLister: Those kinds of questions are never going to be of any use to anyone else but the OP.

Comment: @MrLister They may be good by comparison to really terrible questions, but that doesn't make them good.

Comment: Idea: **You** make a "how to troubleshoot" diagram and start posting links to it in applicable questions.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691

Comment: we ned a homework.stackexchange.com