# Links and buttons in the "Share" box are squished/aligned oddly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, post-menu

When clicking the "Share" button from the post menu (logged in or logged out), the box that appeared that allowed you to copy a link, see the license, and quickly share to social media looked like this as of March 31st, 2021 (taken from an archive of [this ancient post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/11171084)):

[image: Image of the share box]

Now, however, the box that appears has the "Copy link" text squished, and the social buttons aligned oddly, with the license no longer aligning in the center between them as normally expected. Here's a screenshot taken from the live form of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200227/622284):

[image: Showcasing the odd alignment of the various elements below the share text in the share popout]

There seems to have been a change in the layout of this panel, and it's throwing off the alignment of various elements in it. The old one looked quite a bit cleaner, and I'm pretty confident this wasn't an intentional change.

Could this be looked into/fixed?

Comment: Repro'd on Firefox, Edge, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: I thought that is a new design, hereby didn't post a bug report :)

Comment: Yea, this looks like something went wrong with the responsive-design remake they've been working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The buttons in the Share box are now properly aligned:

[image]

Tested in both Chrome and Firefox.